# Move an object along a circle in fabricjs

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

currently I'm using fabricjs to draw on a canvas.

I have one large half-circle and a small circle. I want that the user is able to move the small circle on the outer line of the large half circle. But how can I prevent that the circle leave it's path? The Math is not a problem ;)

EDIT: Here I have some code, that shows you, what I want.

```
            deltaLeft = p.left - centerPointX;
            deltaTop = p.top - centerPointY;
            length = Math.sqrt(deltaLeft * deltaLeft + deltaTop * deltaTop);

            console.log(length);
            if((length <= centerRadius + 5) && (length >= centerRadius - 5) ){
                handleNewX = p.left;
                handleNewY = p.top;
            }else{
                p.left = handleNewX;
                p.top = handleNewY;
            }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/g1h2gL88/

The Problem is, it does not feel naturally to move the handle

Comment: If the Math is not the problem then it is not clear what you mean with `But how can I prevent that the circle leave it's path?`. Add a minimal executable example to your question that allows to reproduce your problem.

Comment: The Problem is, that it feels weird, moving the circle. It does not feel like it's glued to the circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the math, if you want to restrict the moment of the of the object on the circle it would calculate the angle of the vector from center to the mouse position. And then your calculate the new position using the angle and the `centerRadius`. You basically put a straight infinite line starting at the center trough mouse position, and then calculate the intersection of the line with the circle.

```
deltaLeft = p.left - centerPointX;
deltaTop = p.top - centerPointY;

var radians = Math.atan2(deltaTop, deltaLeft)
p.left = Math.cos(radians) * centerRadius + centerPointX
p.top = Math.sin(radians) * centerRadius + centerPointY
```

[jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g1h2gL88/1/)

If you really want to have a range `centerRadius - 5` to `centerRadius + 5` then this can be easily extended to:

```
var length = Math.sqrt(deltaLeft * deltaLeft + deltaTop * deltaTop);

// change the position only if mouse is outside if the centerRadius +/- 5 range
if (length <= centerRadius - 5 || length >= centerRadius + 5) {
  var radians = Math.atan2(deltaTop, deltaLeft)

  if (length < centerRadius) {
    length = centerRadius - 5;
  } else {
    length = centerRadius + 5;
  }
  p.left = Math.cos(radians) * length + centerPointX
  p.top = Math.sin(radians) * length + centerPointY
}
```

[fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/g1h2gL88/2/)